# Can right value is stored in variable when multitple thread set same value to it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'm writing multi thread code on x64 windows msvc.
I don't want to use std::atomic because it flush write combined buffer.

```
static unsigned int value[100];
```

thread1

```
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
{
    if( value[i]== 0 )
    {
        value[i] |= (1 << 2);
    }
}
```

thread2

```
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
{
    if( value[i] == 0 )
    {
        value[i] |= (1 << 2);
    }
}
```

Can value[i] be 0 when it has value 0??

Comment: `I don't want to use std::atomic because it flush write combined buffer.` you can basically read this as `I don't want to use std::atomic because I dont want correct behavoir`.

Comment: The rule is: If you have a shared object accessed between threads, and at least one of those threads is a writer, then you need synchronization. Without that you have data race which is undefined behavior.

Comment: *Does this code cause data race condition?*  Single threaded line of thinking for a multithreaded application.  That's basically what you've posted, thus the answer to your question, quite frankly, is "yes, it can happen".  Don't worry, I have seen many single-thread programmers assume what happens just like your code does, and are shocked when their multithread program fails.

Answer (score 0):

[Mike Vine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2331956/mike-vine) and [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) already answered your question *in the comments*, but here is the explicit one:
**Yes**, your code will cause data race condition.
However, since you are on Windows, you might declare your unsigned int as volatile, even though it is NOT recommended.

A quote from MSDN:

> Microsoft Specific
>
> When the /volatile:ms compiler option is used—by default when
> architectures other than ARM are targeted—the compiler generates extra
> code to maintain ordering among references to volatile objects in
> addition to maintaining ordering to references to other global
> objects. In particular:
>
> A write to a volatile object (also known as volatile write) has
> Release semantics; that is, a reference to a global or static object
> that occurs before a write to a volatile object in the instruction
> sequence will occur before that volatile write in the compiled binary.
>
> A read of a volatile object (also known as volatile read) has Acquire
> semantics; that is, a reference to a global or static object that
> occurs after a read of volatile memory in the instruction sequence
> will occur after that volatile read in the compiled binary.
>
> This enables volatile objects to be used for memory locks and releases
> in multithreaded applications.